# ElasticSearch (Nest) and grouping

Tags: elasticsearch, grouping, nest

We have an index in ElasticSearch whose root document includes a property called Type. Type can have one of the following values:

"Track", "Video","Ringtone".

We want to query the index, and return all documents whose Title property includes "Michael". However, we want exactly 10 documents of each Type in the result set. For example 10 Tracks, 10 Videos and 10 Ringtones whose Title property includes "Michael".

I am using Nest. How can I do this grouping?

Answer (score 0):

Grouping is not yet supported in elasticsearch and thus also not in NEST.

See: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/256